# Flexible web form creation a la Drupal + Content Construction Kit - for Java

Tags: java, drupal, alfresco, drupal-webform

I'm looking for a Java equivalent to Content Construction Kit + contributed fields for Drupal. I'll settle for pretty much any view technology that can run on Tomcat.

The following features are important to me:

- Specify form field types, Ids and labels
- Arbitrary ordering of fields
- Specify form URL and method
- Validation according to field types / regex
- Easily write code to create new field types

The data will be used more for querying than for display - think more "event registration form" than "blog post".

Disclaimer: I'm kind of sure that nothing like this exists. I'd like to confirm that I'm right so that I can tell my boss to hire some PHP developers.

Answer (score 0):

Well, any CMS worth its salt nowadays provides some kind of Custom Content Types. So I'm guessing capable Java CMSes such as Alfresco would provide the same. Here is a interesting link http://www.millarsoft.co.uk/custom-type-example.html about custom content type definition in Alfresco.

I haven't used Alfresco so I don't know if it fulfils all your conditions above or even provides a UI based method of creating custom content types.

Here is an extensive manual on custom content types in alfresco http://ecmarchitect.com/images/articles/alfresco-content/content-article.pdf